# Missing argument 1 for Properties::__construct(),

Tags: php, class, oop

I have written my code locally and everything works fine, I have tried importing it into a new system and are getting the current errors :

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Properties::__construct(), called in 
/home/hghdigib/public_html/system/core/init.php on line 18 and defined in
/home/hghdigib/public_html/classes/properties_data.php on line 8
```

Page to display Function

```
include( str_replace('/core/', '/system/core/init.php', MODX_CORE_PATH) );
$db = new Mysqlidb('localhost','user','pass','database');
$properties = new Properties($db);
$properties->showLatest(3);
```

**Init.php**

```
define('CORE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));

try

{

    require_once("classes/database.php");
    require_once("classes/properties_data.php");
    require_once("classes/xml_upload.php");

}

catch (Exception $e)

{
    die('Error loading system.');
}
```

**Properties_data.php Line 1- 8**

```
    class Properties {
    public $db;
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;    
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: That edit was not an improvement

Comment: Wheres init.php line 18 ? i see only first 7 lines + some lines from IDontKnow.php ...

Comment: How come your not using xPDO?

Comment: It seems your localhost connection is not working, because of connecting to another host, thus passing $db with false result to the Properties constructor causes an error

Comment: That is the whole of init.php as I had spacing in there.

Comment: The local host works already tested, its something todo with the way the class is being picked up.

Comment: Why don't you set use `__construct($db = null)` and then use `if ($db === null) print_r(debug_backtrace());` to figure out where that call comes from?

Comment: @RoyalBg No, it does not matter if `$db` is false or not, if it is being passed to `__construct` it will not raise this warning since no explicit type defined for argument. As the error states code is being called in `core/init.php` so there must be a call to constructor without passing argument

Comment: Ivan Could you please post a answerer how to do this?

Comment: Show us the entire content of `init.php`

Comment: @BrentFrench maybe you need to make a find for containing in your whole project for "new Properties" to see if there's anywhere a call without arguement

Comment: It says it's defined in proeprties_data.php in the error @IvanHušnjak could it be somewhere else?

Comment: Ivan I have updated to the who  init file.

Comment: what is in the line 18 of `init.php`? ... code you showed has } in line 18... which makes no sense for this warning showed

Comment: My code had spacing in so I cleaned up

Comment: Thanks for help guys not sure what happend but used the code bellow and it works not sure why but eh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you use:

```
require_once("classes/database.php");
require_once("classes/properties_data.php");
require_once("classes/xml_upload.php");
```

to require file, check `classes/xml_upload.php`, there may be some code to call `class Properties`.

How to debug? change the `Properties` to:

```
class Properties {
public $db;
function __construct($db = null) {
    if (null == $db) {
        // here you will see the back trace info
        print_r(debug_backtrace());
    }
    $this->db = $db;    
}
```

Comment: I can remove the classes/xml_upload and this still show sames error.

Comment: @BrentFrench, I updated the answer, paste the backtrace info in your question.

Comment: This for some reason fixed the error and works, odd :S Thanks

Comment: @BrentFrench Yeah it works for now, but Property object without $db wont be able to execute db queries later in your application. This is not a solution, just a workaround until it brakes again somewhere else

Comment: Anyway, if `$db` is null, the `debug_backtace` will show up. If that happend, please paste the output here.